# Merge upstream in a subdirectory of my git repo

Tags: git

I've got a git repo, let's say "projectroot".
Now I want to merge from an upstream remote.
I want to merge this content into a specific directory of my "projectroot". For instance, into "projectroot/html".

How can I do this?
If I just do git merge upstream/branchname it will merge it into the "projectroot" directory. But it has to go in "projectroot/html".

It's important to keep the "projectroot" as my git repo.

Kind regards

Comment: Is the upstream repository the one for you project or another remote repository with unrelated history?

Comment: It's another repo than the one on the rootfolder, but the content inside the /html folder comes from that upstream remote, which was moved to the html folder

Comment: Have you checked out git submodules? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: As Mike said, you can use git submodules or [git subtrees](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+into+subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 2 repositories **Repo1** and **Repo2** and you want to move **Repo2** as subdirectory of **Repo1**.

To achieve that we will move the content of **Repo2** into a subfolder under **Repo2** and then merge **Repo1** and **Repo2**.

Below are the detailed steps:

1. Clone both repo on your machine

   `$ git clone Repo1`

   `$ git clone Repo2`
2. Copy the content of Repo2 to a subfolder. Go to the folder Repo2 and apply the following steps: Create a subfolder Repo2

   `$ mkdir Repo2`
3. Move everything from the parent Repo2 to the child Repo2 (except the .git folder) and stage the files (the added folder and deleted file(s)) for a later commit

   `$ git stage Repo2/`

   `$ git stage README.md`
4. Commit and push those changes to git

   `$ git commit -am '[REPO-2] Move content to a subfolder'`

   `$ git push origin master`
5. Go to the folder Repo1 and do the following:
   Add a remote branch with the content of Repo2

   `$ git remote add Repo2Temp (path_to_Repo2)`
6. Fetch Repo2Temp, the temp repo we created in the previous step

   `$ git fetch Repo2Temp`
7. Merge Repo2Temp with Repo1

   `$ git merge Repo2Temp/master`
8. delete the remote Repo2Temp

   `$ git remote rm Repo2Temp`
9. Push the changes to the server

   `$ git push origin master`